# How to setup data model for customizable application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, data-modeling

I have an ASP.NET data entry application that is used by multiple clients.  The application consists of multiple data entry modules that are common to all clients.

I now have multiple clients that want their own custom module added which will typically consist of a dozen or so data points.  Some values will be text, others numeric, some will be dropdown selections, etc.

I'm in need of suggestions for handling the data model for this.  I have two thoughts on how to handle.  First would be to create a new table for each new module for each client.  This is pretty clean but I don't particular like it.  My other thought is to have one table with columns for each custom data point for each client.  This table would end up with a lot of columns and a lot of NULL values.  I don't really like either solution and suspect there's a better way to do this, so any feedback you have will be appreciated.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always with these questions, "it depends".

**The dreaded key-value table.**

This approach relies on a table which lists the fields and their values as individual records.

```
CustomFields(clientId int, fieldName sysname, fieldValue varbinary)
```

Benefits:

- Infinitely flexible
- Easy to implement
- Easy to index
- non existing values take no space

Disadvantage:

- Showing a list of all records with complete field list is a very dirty query

**The Microsoft way**

The Microsoft way of this kind of problem is "sparse columns" (introduced in SQL 2008)

Benefits:

- Blessed by the people who design SQL Server
- records can be queried without having to apply fancy pivots
- Fields without data don't take space on disk

Disadvantage:

- [Many technical restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx)
- a new field requires DML

**The xml tax**

You can add an xml field to the table which will be used to store all the "extra" fields.

Benefits:

- unlimited flexibility
- can be indexed
- storage efficient (when it fits in a page)
- With some xpath gymnastics the fields can be included in a flat recordset.
- schema can be enforced with schema collections

Disadvantages:

- not clearly visible what's in the field
- xquery support in SQL Server has gaps which makes getting your data a real nightmare sometimes

There are maybe more solutions, but to me these are the main contenders. Which one to choose:

- key-value seems appropriate when the number of extra fields is limited. (say no more than 10-20 or so)
- Sparse columns is more suitable for data with many properties which are filled out infrequent. Sounds more appropriate when you can have many extra fields
- xml column is very flexible, but a pain to query. Appropriate for solutions that write rarely and query rarely. ie: don't run aggregates etc on the data stored in this field.

Comment: +1 well organized and informative. I added a link to the xml-eav option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you go with the first option you described.  I wouldn't over think it.  The second option you outlined would be a bad idea in my opinion.

If there are fields common to all the modules you're adding to the system you should consider keeping those in a single table then have other tables with the fields specific to a particular module related back to the primary key in the common table.  This is basically table inheritance (h[ttp://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server)) and will centralize the common module data and make it easier to query across modules.